# How to find the frequency of words in a dictionary (CSV File)

Tags: python, csv

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2RxC.png)I know there are several posts about this on this website. However, my counter function does not work.

I have a CSV file with tweets about sports. I am trying to find the frequency of the following hashtags ["#lovepatriots", "#goJets", etc.] with a total of 10 hashtags.

Below is my code. I want to use the format of the code below instead of a counter function.

```
def readCSV():
    myFile = open("/Users/acantrr/Desktop/south.csv", newline='',   encoding='utf-8"')
    fileString=myFile.read()
    fileString = re.sub ('[^\s\w#]+',' ',fileString)
    fileString = re.sub("\d+", "", fileString)
    fileString  = fileString.lower()
    myFile.close()
    myList= fileString.split()
    return myList

def freqdic():
    myList = readCSV()
    for word in myList:
        # Add a word to my dict. What should the val be?
        if not word_freqs.has_key(word):
            word_freqs[word] = 1
            print('Saw', word, 'for the first time')
        else:
            word_freqs[word] = word_freqs[word]+1
            print('Saw', word, 'again. Doh :(')
```

I am get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

[CSV file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2RxC.png)

Comment: Could you show what the first few lines of your csv file look like?

Comment: So what's wrong with the existing code? Do you get exceptions or just bad results? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: I keep getting the following error when I type in print(freqDict()) in the interactive portion  : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: @StevenRumbalski i posted the first few lines of the CSV file. Also I am trying to count the specific times certain hashtags show up in a dictionary ... sportsDict =[#word1, #word2, etc] . So I am not sure if the answer below is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

This error

```
 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

tells me you are using Python 3.

From [What's New in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> Removed. `dict.has_key()` – use the `in` operator instead.

To fix your problem change

```
if not word_freqs.has_key(word):
```

to

```
if word not in word_freqs:
```

Better yet, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and your function becomes:

```
def freqdic():
    words = readCSV()
    word_freqs = collections.Counter(words)
    return word_freqs
```

or even

```
def freqdic():
    return collections.Counter(readCSV())
```

Comment: Thank you Steven. This was very helpful and helped me figure out a few other things!